# Controls.Find method returns nothing when cast as ComboBox[]

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a method that searches in all controls on a tab sheet and returns ones, matching a string ([Controls.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method). Since I am sure only one control is going to be found and that control is a combo box I have tried to cast it but it acts weird.

This code executes correctly:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
        String Name = cb.Name;
        Name = Name.Replace("Rank", "Target");
        Control[] ar = cb.Parent.Controls.Find(Name, false);
        MessageBox.Show(ar.Length.ToString());
        if (ar.Length > 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("More than one \"Target\" combo box has been found as the corresponding for the lastly modified \"Rank\" combo box.");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = cb.SelectedIndex; i < Ranks.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                //ar[0].Items.Add(Ranks[i]); - this does not work, since Controls don't have a definition for "Items"
            }
        }
    }
```

This code's Controls.Find method does not return anything:

```
private void Enchantments_ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
        String Name = cb.Name;
        Name = Name.Replace("Rank", "Target");
        ComboBox[] ar = (ComboBox[])cb.Parent.Controls.Find(Name, false); //Also tried "as ComboBox, instead of "(ComboBox)" if it matters
        MessageBox.Show(ar.Length.ToString()); //Raises an exception as arr[] is null
        if (ar.Length > 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("More than one \"Target\" combo box has been found as the corresponding for the lastly modified \"Rank\" combo box.");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = cb.SelectedIndex; i < Ranks.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                ar[0].Items.Add(Ranks[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I wonder why it returns nothing when cast as a ComboBox and how I can alleviate this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) method signature:

```
public Control[] Find(string key, bool searchAllChildren)
```

The result is of type of control array. And even if all controls of the array was of type of `ComboBox` the result is not of type of `ComboBox[]`, so the cast returns null.

If you need a `ComboBox` array, you can simply use:

```
ComboBox[] result = cb.Parent.Controls.Find(Name, false).OfType<ComboBox>().ToArray();
```

Also if you are sure all returned elements are of type of `ComboBox`, you also can use `Cast<ComboBox>()` instead of `OfTYpe<ComboBox>()`.

When all elements are of the same type, you can use `Cast<T>`, when some elements may be of type of `K` but you only want the elements of type `T`, you can use `OfType<T>`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! So, my mistake was not knowing that casting something as a certain type does not atler what type a method would return?

Comment: When you try to cast `SomeValue as SomeType`, the cast is successful only if the `SomeValue` is really of type of `SomeType`. Your mistakke here is, you expected the cast can convert `Control[]` to `ComboBox[]`. A control array which contains some combobox is not of type of `ComboBox[]`. To convert it to a combo box list, if you know all elements are of type of `ComboBox`, you can use `Cast<ComboBox>()` if elements may contain some other controls as well, you can limit the result to combo boxes only, using `OfType<ComboBox>()`.